# location of the vector where maximum value contain

Tags: visual-c++, vector, arraylist

Can someone help me to find the location of the vector where maximum value contain. I am using visual C++.

```
std::vector<double> array;
```

Lets say:

```
array = {19.4 , 45.0 ,12.9 ,59.3 , 2.8 ,18.0}
```

The maximum value is `59.3`. I want to populate its location.

```
max_location = 3;
```

Is there any way to get it...? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a homework, I won't post a complete solution, just an idea. Take a look on `std::max_element`(for example, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)) . It returns an iterator, and if it is not equal your `array.end()` you can get a distance between it and `array.begin()` which will be the index you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's think this out.  You want to go through the vector one by one and find the maximum vaue; you want to keep track of the value's index.  Here's some pseudocode:

```
 index = 0
 for each value in the array from 0 to end
    if this is the highest value you've seen so far
       save value
       save index of value

 print index
```

How can you do these in C++?